# Javascript string comparison not exactly equal to

Tags: javascript

Newbie here, so please be kind. With Javascript, say I have 2 timestamps expressed as strings, 2017-09-14 11:49:06.277 (created) and 2017-09-14 11:49:06.978 (modified). Trying to do a comparison such that if created is within the same second as modified, do one thing, else do a different thing. How does one compare the  strings starting with the year, then month, day and so on down to seconds?

Comment: Why don't you just remove everything starting with `.` and compare the result?

Comment: convert to dates and do the math....

Comment: Do you mean within the same "whole" second as measured by a wall clock, or simply that the file is modified < 1s after it was created.   It would seem unlikely that you'd want to disregard the case when a file is created at e.g. 11:49:06.999 and then modified 1ms later.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow..What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help!

Comment: U can use moment.js to do these kinds of operations easily.Just go through it's docs it's very easy

Answer (score 2):

Compare them as *ms from 1970* maybe:

```
 if( Math.abs( new Date(a) - new Date(b) ) < 1000 /*ms = 1s */) alert("a and b occured in the same second");
```

( up to one second difference)

or based on [@barmans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) idea:

```
if( a.split(".")[0] === b.split(".")[0] ) alert("a and b occured in the same second");
```

(Same second)

both codes need *a* and *b* to be defined e.g:

```
 const
   a = "2017-09-14 11:49:06.277",
   b = "2017-09-14 11:49:06.978";
```

Comment: This will treat `11:49:06.999` as the same second as `11:49:07:001`.

Comment: @Barmar the OP is vague on that point

Comment: He says he wants to compare each component from year down to second. That sounds like he just wants to ignore the fraction.

Comment: @Barmar in which case he's probably got an XY problem...

Comment: Your answer is probably what he really wants to do, but he needs to say so.

Comment: @barmar yeah, added your comment as code too, if youd like to answer on your own, i will remove it.

Comment: FWIW, if you know in advance that the input is a well-formatted ISO8601 date/timestamp you could just check for `a.substr(0, 19) === b.substr(0, 19)` and avoid the scan for the period character and the comparatively expensive `split` function call.

Comment: Sorry for being too vague. 

If a = "2017-09-14 11:49:06.277" and b = "2017-09-14 11:49:06.978", I'm needing to compare a to b such that if b occurs between "2017-09-14 11:49:06.000" and 2017-09-14 11:49:06.999", then write "timestamps are equal" else "timestamps are not equal".

Is this any more clear?